# High school algebra,math competition problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let:  $$
\sqrt{x^2 +\sqrt[3]{x^4} \cdot \sqrt[3]{y^2}} + \sqrt{y^2+\sqrt[3]x^2\cdot\sqrt[3]y^4} = a
$$
Calculate
$$
\sqrt[3]{x^2} + \sqrt[3]{y^2} - \sqrt[3]{a^2} = ?                 
$$
Edit: Really sorry for posting the wrong problem

Comment: what do you think is a possible approach to this problem?

Comment: I really have no idea, tried squaring, cubing "a" but nothing. Tried squaring, or rationalizing second expression but it just gets more and more complicated.

Comment: Just replace $a$ in the expression you want by the left-hand side in the given equation. There is no much more to be done with the problem as written.

Comment: Are there any restrictions on $x, y, a$? Are they integers, natural numbers, real?

Comment: Your problem is not correct

Comment: The problem doesn't state anything, so I guess they could be complex?

Comment: You could try the substitutions $A=x^{2/3}$ and $B=y^{2/3}$ to give $$A\sqrt{A+B}+B^2\sqrt A=a$$